# How to Download bulk of images and save it to core data in swift?

Tags: swift, core-data

In the app I am currently working, I need to download 100+ image and save it to core data. as soon as I open the ViewController

Note: I have already tried using Kingfisher or SDWebImage to cache the image and save it for a long time by setting the cache age to 7 days or longer but it didn't work. it just keeps downloading the same image again instead of using it from the cache image after few hours.

All I want is to download the Image once and save it.

My current Implementation for downloading image looks like this.

Note: That I am storing the image as binary data with (Allows external storage)

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5;

for url in imageUrls {
    queue.addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in

        let img1 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(url)

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
                // Add to context
                AddToContext(image: img1)
        })
    }


}
```

Or should I just store the image in Document dir?

Comment: use https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher library ..

Comment: @vaibhav thanks for the reply. Kingfisher is for Image Caching. I don't wanna cache the Image as it doesn't fit my requirement, I have also tried SDWebImage too.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: @user9943042 you can ignore maintaining cache once your start applying the diff-2 downloading methods.

Comment: @vaibhav sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ImageCache of Kingfisher

**First step:** Look for the image in cache

```
ImageCache.default.isImageCached(forKey: "key_for_image")
```

If image is found, you can retrieve it using:

```
ImageCache.default.retrieveImage(forKey: "key_for_image", options: nil) { 
}
```

*Note: You can also use retrieveImage instead of isImageCached, and check if the image is nil*

**Second step**: Download the image if it's not already in cache

```
ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: url, options: [], progressBlock: nil) {
}
```

**Third step**: Store the image (you can use any variant of the store image)

```
ImageCache.default.store(image, forKey: "key_for_image")
```

**Example 1**:

```
let isImageCached = ImageCache.default.isImageCached(forKey: "key_for_image")
if isImageCached {
    ImageCache.default.retrieveImage(forKey: "key_for_image", options: nil) { image, cacheType in
    imageView.image = image
} else {
    ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: url, options: [], progressBlock: nil) { (image, error, url,data) in
        if let image = image {
            imageView.image = image
            ImageCache.default.store(image, forKey: "key_for_another_image") 
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2**:

```
ImageCache.default.retrieveImage(forKey: "key_for_image", options: nil) { image, cacheType in
    if let image = image {
        imageView.image = image
    } else {
        ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: url, options: [], progressBlock: nil) { (image, error, url,data) in
        if let image = image {
            imageView.image = image
            ImageCache.default.store(image, forKey: "key_for_image") 
        }
    }
}
```

One possibility for key_for_image can be MD5 hash of the url.

Kingfisher cheatsheet can be found [here](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet)

Comment: Thanks For reply I will Try this